# Adding sort to mongo JSON @Query with Spring Data Repository

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data

I want to sort the results of a `find` using the [mongo JSON query](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-document/docs/current/reference/html/#d0e3293) and having done some reading and experimenting, I still can't get it to work. I have got the [PagingAndSortingRepository](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-commons/docs/1.2.0.M1/api/org/springframework/data/repository/PagingAndSortingRepository.html) and can use [`Sort()`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-commons/docs/1.2.0.M1/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Sort.html) on *findAll* with no problems.

#### Repository class

```
public interface ThingRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Thing, ObjectId> {
    @org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.Query("{ name:?0, $or : [ { state:'new' } , {state:'updated'} ] }")
    List<Device> findThingsInNewOrUpdatedState(String name);
}
```

#### Service layer

```
@Service
public class ThingService() {
    @Autowired private ThingRepository thingRepository;

    public List<Thing> getSortedThings() {
        return (List<Thing>)thingRepository.findAll(new Sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, Arrays.asList("dateModified")));
    }

    public List<Thing> getNewOrUpdatedThingsSorted() {
        return thingRepository.findThingsInNewOrUpdatedState(); // <-- this needs to be sorted
    }
}
```

The query is translated directly into the mongoDb call, which works fine

```
db.things.find({ name:'xxx', $or : [ { state:'new' }, {state:'updated'} ] })
```

and I know I can add a [`sort()`](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%7B%7Bsort%28%29%7D%7D) in regular mongoDb syntax but cannot work out how to do this from within Java/Spring Data. It tried adding it to the @Query but it was not working, since I think Spring is just executing a [`find()`](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Querying).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to simply add a `Sort` parameter to the query method and thus dynamically pipe in `Sort` instances that will be applied to the query defined in `@Query`.

Comment: Hmm, I'm pretty sure I tried that, but I might be wrong. I will give it another go later today and get back to you.

Comment: Sorry, only just got round to trying this. The sorting is working fine as a parameter to the method, e.g. `List<Thing> findByThingId(String thingId, Sort sort);` but I cannot use the `Sort` with an annotated custom query, e.g. `@org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.Query`. Any ideas?

Comment: So you say piping in the `Sort` does not have effect as soon as you manually define the query using `@Query`? If that's the case please open a JIRA ticket.

Comment: Thanks for your help Oliver. I've raised as an enhancement - [DATAMONGO-323](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/DATAMONGO-323)

Comment: Bug fixed. Will be available in tonight's snapshot as well as the upcoming 1.0 RC1 release.

Comment: Thanks and confirmed as working for me with spring-data-mongodb-1.0.0.BUILD-20111125.093023-501.jar. I was using mongo-java-driver v2.6.4 which was giving a com.mongodb.ReadPreference class not found error when I started using the snapshot. This was easily fixed by upgrading to v2.7.2.

Comment: @OliverGierke: Does it mean one can specify annotation as `@Query("{ name: ?0 }.sort( { 'age': 1 } )")`? And is this available in `spring-data-mongodb-1.0.0.RELEASE`?

Comment: No,please re-read the comments. The method declaration is shown above. Annotate this one with `@Query("{ 'name' : ?0 }")` and hand a `new Sort(Order.ASC, "age")` to the method.

Comment: to do multiple sorts you can create multiple Sort.Order objects and create a Sort object using the Sort(List<Order>) constructor